# Fade in effect for list items

Tags: android

I have to display a list with a similar display to the pic. I've searched a lot but haven't found a particular solution for implementation.

[image]

Comment: thanks grlshu. but i have done this with list customization. Thanks for help man.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom component.
You can make your own component like that.

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) is a demo application for wheel view component.

Also check [Simple Wheel View](http://sunilsuthar02.blogspot.in/2012_10_01_archive.html)